# Android application with Parse - How to respond to events on the server side

Tags: android, parse-platform, event-handling, server-side, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to write an android application, and I chose to handle the server side with parse.
Suppose I have three tables, ***TableA***, ***TableB*** and ***TableC***. I want to call a server-side function each time a row is added to one of my tables, that is: call ***f<sub>a</sub>*** when a row is added to ***TableA***, ***f<sub>b</sub>*** when a row is added to ***TableB*** and ***f<sub>c</sub>*** when a row is added to ***TableC***.

I've read the *[Parse Javascript Guide](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide)* for server-side code from beginning to end, but could not find any useful information. Would much appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand from your question that, you want to call separate functions for your table add row operations.  So, in android side you can differentiate which table is currently used. So based on used table, you can trigger cloud function  via ;

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("tableAFunction", params, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void done(Object response, ParseException exc) {
        Log.e("cloud code example", "response: " + response);
    }
});
```

Via this approach, you can call different cloud function based on table selection. In addition, you can send parameters via filling the params hash table (key-value structure.) Hope this helps.

Regards.